# Nvidia GTX 760 and 960 fan always loud on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, fan

I have a long standing issue with my Nvidia GPUs: when Windows 10 boots up, just before the login screen and home menu, the GPU fan becomes very loud, until shutdown. It does that with either my GTX 760 or my GTX 960.

I remember that this issue appeared after the second boot of this installation. It doesn't happen on any other OS (Linux-based or FreeBSD) or in the UEFI/"bios" menu, meaning it specifically happens in Windows 10. When there are major updates with multiple reboots, it seems to happen only when Nvidia driver is loaded (which is up-to-date, of course) - it's not happening when I see that fonts aren't anti-aliased and it's tearing which probably means that Nvidia driver isn't loaded; I think that during updates, only trusted and mandatory software is started.

I don't expect this issue to come from any malware, I had a paid Bit Defender installed that never detected anything (that's why I stopped to use it, I'm a too cautious user). Monitoring software only show minimal GPU usage when idling, Process Explorer with Virus Total shows that all running processes are known and sane.

I changed the whole computer pieces except the Windows 10 installation and the GPUs (new motherboard, CPU, power supply), and I'm positive the noise come from the GPU fan.

I haven't found any setting controlling GPU fan speed in Nvidia settings, it seems to exist for other GPUs.

I'm out of ideas, I've read many forum posts, never found a solution (except maybe buying an AMD GPU, but I don't like wasting hardware that still work and it costs money).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use [GPU-Z](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) to watch your GPU temperature.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, I just had to look into the computer with more light. One of the two GPU fans was off, and rotating it manually (while on) make it started and the other decreased speed (and noise stopped).